# i am getting these errors , please guide me how to fix it?

Tags: android, android-layout

hi please help me how to fix that problems, it occurs in login and sign up page
so its crashed my application , please help me to get rid of these errors.

[i am attaching error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7rPI.png)

The errors are render problem:

```
Couldn't resolve resource @string/path_password_strike_through
Failed to parse file C:\Users\Kashi\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-28.0.0-alpha3.aar\56e65747003de1b867e35f7882861c1e\res\drawable-v21\avd_show_password.xml
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".activities.log_in">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutEmail"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextEmail"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:hint="Email" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextPassword"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:hint="Password" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:text="Login"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/forgottonPassword"
        android:text="Forgotton Password"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linkRegister"
        android:text="Don't have an account ? Register now"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Check for the string resources are they valid or present in the string file. Also post your logcat error . Are you setting drawable for password field?

Comment: the logcat error list is too much long

Comment: hi i found a error my android version is latest 3,2 and its not support <android.support.design. widget .TextInputLayout> , so is there is any option to work in widgets like that in new version?

Comment: You have to add design dependency to your App level gradle dependencies like this{
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    ...
}

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug [check the issue tracker here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116076358)

> The issue was in handling resource resolution inside aapt attributes.
>   This has been fixed in Android Studio 3.3 canary

Comment: where is android 3.3 ? the latest version of android studio is 3.2.1 in android website

Comment: @WaqasFarooq you can download it from here [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/)

Answer (score 0):

The xml file you posted has no references to any string resource called "path_password_strike_through"

But I think you have unfortunately remove this key string or never created it in your strings.xml

Comment: hi i found a error my android version is latest 3,2 and its not support <android.support.design. widget .TextInputLayout> , so is there is any option to work in widgets like that in new version?