# how to fix material button error in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

i am trying to use material button in my xml design but i found an error.
missing classes
android.support.design.button.MaterialButton class not found

how i can fix this error ?
my xml and dependencies are attached

this is my xml code

```
<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:text="Login"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using older version of libraries.

In order to use Material Components you need to either use the **Migrate to Androidx** option from Refactor in Android Studio 3.2 or greater.

and use this library

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`

Or if you want to keep using the Support Libraries then you need to update your libraries to v28.0.0

For more you can refer this link :  [Material Components Getting Started](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/)

**Do not use  com.android.support and com.google.android.material dependencies in your app at the same time.**

To upgrade your libraries to 28.0.0 :

In your app gradle file set your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 28

and change your support library numbers to 28.0.0 for e.g

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Comment: how i can upgrade libraries to v28.0.0?

Comment: Updated my answer to this query. Make sure you are using updated Android Studio i.e Android Studio v3.2.1 is the latest.

Comment: i am using android 2.3.3 because in updated version of 3.2.1 android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout is not working so what should i do?

Comment: I am currently using 3.2.1 and TextInputLayout works just fine in this too for me.

Comment: then please check this question that i ask earlier and tell me solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52735405/i-am-getting-these-errors-please-guide-me-how-to-fix-it/52735883#52735883